# TYPO3 New content type icons are not showing in page preview window

Tags: php, typo3, content-type, typoscript

I have created my own CTypes and a custom Layout for backend page view and I'm struggling with one small thing:

My new content elements use TYPO3 built in icons. They are working fine in content selection:

[image]

but don't get used in the Page view template layout. Instead default element icon is used.

Any idea why and how to fix this?

*PS: Can show the config, just request which ones exactly*

Comment: @eisbehr Yes, thank you. That worked like a charm. Please make an answer from this comment so I can accept and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this icon visible in those content lists too, you need to add it to the `TCA`. For example, in `ext/my_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['ctrl']['typeicon_classes']['my_extension_content'] = 'icon_from_icon_registry';
```